# Where is she? or Where is she at?

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is grammatically correct?  I have been trying to find the answer to this for a couple years.  I hear people saying both of these types of sentences and I keep wondering which is grammatically correct.  I have researched online but cannot find out, so I decided to ask you.  thank you.

Comment: "Where is she?" is standard English, and "where is she at?" is a US local dialect, mainly Southern.

Answer (score -1):

Both are acceptable. The first is uncontroversial and I do not discuss it here.

It is common usage to say things such as "*She is at the cinema*", "*He is at the bar*", "*She was at the races*", "*He is at home*". The "*Where is he/she at?*" questioning construction parallels these statements so finds itself in frequent and acceptable usage.

The "*at*" is redundant. It is not needed because the questions could be more concisely put as "*Where is she/he*?".

This redundancy, and the efforts of seventeenth and eighteenth century grammarians to align English with Latin, lead some people to say it is ungrammatical to end with "*at*". But it is not: see https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepositions-ending-a-sentence-with for a reasoned historical discussion.

Comment: Mystery down-marker fails to explain what they disagree with. So what is the point they dislike? How can we possibly learn from mute negativity?